# org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry - Issue of WSO2 AM with Java 8

Tags: java-8, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to setup the **WSO2 API Manager** in **window 10 with JDK 1.8**. While trying to start the server, I'm getting below error.

I followed the link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Running+the+Product

and **hosts** file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

# Added by Docker for Windows
192.168.0.6 host.docker.internal
192.168.0.6 gateway.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Error:

```
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,128]  INFO - AndesKernelBoot Andes MessageStore initialised with org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,174]  INFO - ClusterManager Initializing Standalone Mode. Current Node ID:NODE:DESKTOP-NQ639DU/192.168.99.1 192.168.99.1
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,273]  INFO - Andes Andes API initialised.
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,314]  INFO - AndesChannel Channel created (ID: Internel_channel)
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,324]  INFO - AndesKernelBoot Syncing exchanges, queues, bindings and subscriptions
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,326]  INFO - InboundDBSyncRequestEvent Running DB sync task.
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,340]  INFO - Andes Starting Safe Zone Calculator for slots.
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,388] ERROR - Main Exception during startup. Triggering shutdown
org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:307)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startup(Broker.java:110)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.startBroker(Main.java:217)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.execute(Main.java:206)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.<init>(Main.java:54)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.main(Main.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAndesBroker(QpidServiceComponent.java:396)
        at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.activate(QpidServiceComponent.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.internal.ServerAdminServiceComponent.activate(ServerAdminServiceComponent.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not bind to /0.0.0.0:5672
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.accept(MinaNetworkTransport.java:155)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startAMQPListener(Broker.java:201)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:294)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.registerNew(SocketAcceptor.java:363)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.access$800(SocketAcceptor.java:55)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor$Worker.run(SocketAcceptor.java:222)
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,395]  INFO - ApplicationRegistry Shutting down ApplicationRegistry(org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@6d63758)
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,401]  INFO - ApplicationRegistry Shutting down ApplicationRegistry:org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@6d63758
[2019-05-18 11:46:57,403]  INFO - PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager Unregistering UserManagementMBean
```

Comment: which version of WSO2-APIM you are using ? I don't think it's related with Java version. Here I can see it's occurred due to `Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind` might be some port is already in use, which is used by wso2-am. Here is the port [info](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Default+Product+Ports)

Comment: @AshwinK - I am using latest version 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because you have running another message broker in the same port(5672). you have to stop that server before starting the APIM. (ex like rabbit mq: service rabbitmq-server stop )

Answer (score 0):

As the port is already in use change port in `\conf\carbon.xml`.

Comment: Nope, even after restarting my machine, getting same error. Seriously something wrong

Comment: have you changed the port

Comment: Nope, I've not changed anything. Could you please share doc to setup the WSO2 AM?

Comment: check which service is consuming 9443 port